# Python use implicit argument on new class without pre constructing Object from class that inherits: pandas, Quandl, matplotlib, NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, quandl

I'm new to python as to artificial intelligence.
I'm using `matplotlib` to plot the curve of data in a `pandas dataframe` that I get with `Quandl`.
In examples, I'm seeing stuff like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import Quandl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = Quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df[['Adj. Close']].plot()
plt.show()
```

How does the `xml` or `json` returned from `Quandl` gets immediately converted into a `pandas` object (`dataframe` I guess).

Other than that, I want to know how is the `pandas serie` that I get from the `dataframe` able to be passed as an implicit argument to the `.plot()` method from another library (`matplotlib`) without even constructing an object from `matplotlib` that inherits the `pandas serie` class.

I mean how and why was I able to directly write `pandas_series_object.plot()` in `df[['Adj. Close']].plot()` instead of `plotter.plot(df[['Adj. Close']])`

Thanks in advance!!

If someone came here after watching [sentdex's python machine learning series tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OGxgnH8y2NM&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDfKTOs3Keq_kaG2P55YRn5v), that Question/Answer is just for it.

Comment: `Quandl.get` doesn't return `xml` or `json` it returns [a pandas DataFrame](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-python/blob/b279995ffa6e42d43e0e16397e0e140f6d7e551b/quandl/get.py#L63) as per their source-code. If you want to know how they do it, then I suggest you start by reading the source-code there.

Comment: oh okay Hampus thankss, and what about the pandas_serie.plot()  ??

Comment: You question is a run-on-sentence and is very hard to decipher exactly what you want help with. Could you please rephrase the question and show some code (pseudo other real, doesn't matter) for what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Updated it. I think it's clearer what I'm not understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what Hampus Larsson said in the comment was part of the answer, `Quandl.get` returns a `pandas dataframe` and not `xml` nor `json`, at least for the `python` implementation of `Quandl` as cited on https://www.quandl.com/tools/python ,
It says:

> Quandl requires NumPy (v1.8 or above) and pandas (v0.14 or
>   above) to work.

For the other part of the question regarding `matplotlib` being called as such `df[['Adj. Close']].plot()`, I've found online on both websites of `matplotlib` and `pandas` that they extend each other with wrapper functions hard-coded in their libraries and that's why it works.
References:

On pandas website: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13/visualization.html

On matplolib's website: https://matplotlib.org/thirdpartypackages/index.html#gui-applications